# Not using operator '?' properly?

Tags: c++, return, operator-keyword

So I've got function returning an integer along with some max and min value for it. I wanted to do it with nice and clean one-liner at the end:

```
(freq>max_freq) ? return max_freq : ((freq<min_freq) ? return min_freq : return freq);
```

but what I get is

```
posplot.hh:238:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
     (freq>max_freq) ? return max_freq : ((freq<min_freq) ? return min_freq : return freq);}
                     ^
posplot.hh:238:21: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘return’
posplot.hh:238:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
posplot.hh:238:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
```

So, is that because using return here is a dumb thing to do and I should make it some other way or could it work but I screwed up? I'm quite curious cause I think I've used '?' operator as neater if-else for a lot of stuff and it always worked fine. Can someone explain why it happens?

Comment: The operands to ?: have to be expressions. `return someExpression;` is a statement and `return someExpression` without the semicolon is invalid. I'd suggest using `std::max` and `std::min` for this instead as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the return before the ternary operators:

```
return (freq>max_freq) ? max_freq : ((freq<min_freq) ? min_freq : freq);
```

Basically, the ternary operator is expected to evaluate to a single value on each branch (which means it needs to be 3 *expressions*, and you're creating one expression and two *statements*, since `return` creates a statement).

Comment: Thanks a lot (also for more detailed explanation), I really should've tried it, it even looks more logical than my line.

Answer (score 3):

The operands of the conditional operator (like most other operators) must be *expressions* not *statements*, so they can't be return-statements.

The conditional expression itself has a value: the value of the chosen operand. Evaluate that, and return it:

```
return (freq>max_freq) ? max_freq : ((freq<min_freq) ? min_freq : freq);
```

Answer (score 2):

? operator can be used in expressions. return is a statement

your one-liner may look like this:

```
return (freq>max_freq ? max_freq : (freq<min_freq ? min_freq : freq));
```